# Syntax error, DEBUG showing error in urls.py?

Tags: python, django, url, view, django-urls

So, I'm very confused, everything worked perfectly in my app, I made some changes that I then reverted in my app. However, this resulted in an error at my login page:

```
SyntaxError at /login/
invalid syntax (views.py, line 41)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://X.X.X.X:8000/login/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (views.py, line 41)
Exception Location: /path/to-app/project-name/app (same name as project)/urls.py in <module>, line 22
```

This is my url.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from import views
import overtime.views
import schedule.views

urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^login/', views.login_user),
url(r'^index/', views.index),
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^login_success/$', views.login_success, name='login_success'), 
url(r'^overtime/',include('overtime.urls')),
url(r'^schedule/',include('schedule.urls')),       
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page':     '/login'}),
]
```

I've tried many vairations of the view import, all resulting in the same syntax error:

from . import views
from MonolithEmployee import *
import views
import MonolithEmployee.views

Every one of these results in a syntax error.

Is it possible this is a problem somewhere else?

This is the view it appears to be quoting:

```
# user login
@login_required
def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("login_success")
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
            context = {'form': form}
            return render_to_response('login.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        ''' user is not submitting the form, show the login form '''
        form = LoginForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('login.html', context,     context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def login_success(request):
    """
    Redirects users based on the group they are in 
    """
    if request.user.groups.filter(name="BAML").exists():
        return redirect("")
    else:
        return redirect("index")

def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render_to_response('index.html', context, RequestContext(request))

def index_BAML(request):
    context = {}
    return render_to_response('.html', context, RequestContext(request
```

Comment: What is on the 40-42 lines in views.py?

Comment: @AaronLayfield Your 41 line is incomplete....I'm not sure whether you've to paste here or that's the one creating bug..

Comment: It was actually the last line in the code as per Serjiks reply, such a silly mistake on my part, but the error wasn't as informative as it could have been.

Nevertheless, stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code:

```
def index_BAML(request):
    context = {}
    return render_to_response('index_BAML.html', context, RequestContext(request
```

You just left the last paratheses:

```
def index_BAML(request):
    context = {}
    return render_to_response('index_BAML.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```